# SSIS or SQL Agent weird error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssis, sql-server-agent, ssis-2012

We are like SSIS heavy shop and there are more than 30+ packages that runs in that 24 hr cycle. However, lately every few other weeks we are noticing that the packages fail to execute and throws out this error provided below in the job log. Our packages are configured either through SSIS catalog or through packages stored in msdb. However, both of them are failing. I came across one of the articles from Microsoft and this is the only article that is an exact replica of what I am facing in my environment but even after applying the same solution I am back to square one with the error re-appearing. I've provided the environment details below. Can someone point me in the right direction.

[SSIS package fails with error : The step did not generate any output. The return value was unknown](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2014/05/21/ssis-package-fails-with-error-the-step-did-not-generate-any-output-the-return-value-was-unknown)

Message:

> Executed as user: x. The step did not generate any output.  The return value was unknown.  The process exit code was -1073741502.  The step failed.

SQL Environment Details:->
SQL Server 2012 SP3,
Windows Server 2012 Datacenter (x64),
RAM: 28 GB,
Only a single SQL instance running on the machine and there maybe a couple of other services but that's all.

Comment: To confirm: Your package is set up to use SSIS Logging, you're set up to log messages OnError and OnWarning, and nothing is being logged? And, all SSIS packages run by jobs are failing, every time?

Comment: Yes...that is true.

Comment: Did the solution in the link you provided work for a while? And, did it include restarting the server?

Comment: Your post sounds like the problem stopped after the registry change, then started up again; wondering if a factor other than the registry change was involved 9like a server restart). Not that regular server restarts are an optimal solution, necessarily - but it would indicate more symptoms to consider.

Comment: Yes every time this issue happens I can't really do anything but forced to restart the server. However, this has become a more frequent event these days and I can't really figure out where else to look for.

Comment: Logically, if things work OK for a while when the server reboots, then something is happening over time that eventually causes the failures. It could be some sort of resource consumption issue (for example a memory leak in something running on the server); a job or query running an infinite loop of some sort; or any of a number of other things. As a stopgap measure, if there's a time when you could safely schedule a nightly restart for the server, that might at least buy you time.

Comment: As a further diagnostic step, build an SSIS package that doesn't really do anything (like, a ForEach loop container that operates on all files in a given directory that match the file name pattern ZZXXQQ.edcba (making sure there are no such files). Job should need very little in the way of resources to run. If this still runs when other jobs won't, then it might be a resource issue.

Comment: Also - if you do decide to restart regularly, try to check the various performance counter dmv views, to see if there are any irregularities before you restart.

Comment: Can't think of anything else terribly likely to help - sorry.